# How to customize Helm buffers' mode-line

Tags: helm, mode-line, mode-line-format

I'm trying to customize Helm buffers' mode-line.

I have set `mode-line-format` with `powerline` package:

```el
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 '("%e"
   (:eval
    (let* ((active (powerline-selected-window-active))

           ;; Conditionnal faces (in function of `active')
           ...

           ;; Left elements
           (lhs ...)

           ;; Right elements
           (rhs ...))

      ;; Build the result
      (concat
       (powerline-render lhs)
       (powerline-fill mode-line-3-face (powerline-width rhs))
       (powerline-render rhs))))))
```

From what I understand from `helm-mode-line-string`'s documentation:

> Help string displayed in mode-line in `helm'. It can be a string or a list of two args, in this case, first arg is a string that will be used as name for candidates number, second arg any string to display in mode line. If nil, use default`mode-line-format'.

I should be able to have my customized mode-line everywhere (in every buffers) with:

```el
(setq-default helm-mode-line-string nil)
```

Isn't [this line](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/c59386797abaa91b9f8dec5a5ac48bf24e4bd7e3/helm.el#L3846) from helm.el supposed to do exactly what I want?

```el
(setq mode-line-format (default-value 'mode-line-format))
```

---

### Edit

Works as intended with: `helm-colors`, `helm-projectile-ag`, `helm-projectile-grep`.

But not with: `helm-M-x`, `helm-projectile-find-file`, `helm-projectile-switch-project`.

Comment: Yes, it is, setting `helm-mode-line-string` to nil will keep helm from building its own `mode-line-format`, which works as expected (I can confirm).

Comment: And yet I still get the Helm-made on `helm-M-x`, any idea? Update post.

Comment: I get it too. I didn't test it carefully.  `helm-mode-line-string` will not matter if helm source has `'mode-line` slot set, such as in `helm-M-x` and `helm-regexp`.  Since helm sets its own `mode-line-format` in `helm-display-mode-line`, you can set your `mode-line-format` there by advising the function (spaceline's `spaceline-helm-mode` is using this way: https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline/blob/2d07d8f85fb0b46c3e52c737b03fe44450140656/spaceline-config.el#L104-L124).

Comment: I had no idea someone had extracted Spacemacs' powerline! I originally gave up on using Spacemacs' source and started to build my own mode-line. Probably going to give this one a shot since I got a tad more proficient with Emacs Lisp :) thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spaceline](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline) helped me customize the mode-line for Helm buffers (uses `helm-alive-p`).